# Cannot import functions from another file in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import, export

In my typescript file, I have these functions:

```
export {convertToArray, getColumn}


function convertToArray(fileName: string): StringTable {
  ...
}

function getColumn(columnName: string, table: StringTable): string[] {
  ...
}
```

And I'm trying to import them in another Typescript file:

```
import {convertToArray, getColumn} from './csv-reader'
```

But now it's telling me that my functions are declared locally but never exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you exported them before defining them. Try with:

```
export function convertToArray(fileName: string): StringTable {
  ...
}

export function getColumn(columnName: string, table: StringTable): string[] {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Same error.. Its a TypeError telling me that csv_reader_1.converToArray is not a function.